# why component in not loaded while using react router dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

could you please tell me why component is not loaded when router changes

router file

```
export default function ForceLayoutRouter() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/calender" exact>
            <ForceCalender />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/home" exact>
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

link file

```
<Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]}>
            <Menu.Item key="1" icon={<UserOutlined />}>
              <NavLink to={`/home`} exact>
                Home ex
              </NavLink>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2" icon={<CalendarOutlined />}>
              <NavLink to={`/calender`}>Calender</NavLink>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="3" icon={<LogoutOutlined />}>
              Logout
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
```

when I click `home` or calender link it change the router but component is not loaded.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-black-3yozm?file=/src/components/layout.js:730-1230

Comment: The code is very confusing and needs to be structured clearly. It's best if file names match the component name. You are trying to use <AppRouter /> and importing AppRouter from `./router` but inside the `router.js` you have declared it as `ForceAppRouter` so that would be the first thing to look at. You should wrap the `<Router>` around your Layout and then you should have your `Switch` with `Route` just before the closing `layout` tag `</Layout>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your app within a single `Router`. Try remove `Router` in your `ForceLayoutRouter`.

```
export default function ForceLayoutRouter() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/calender" exact>
          <ForceCalender />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/home" exact>
          <Home />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's the working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-grass-tnq63?file=/src/layout2.js